# How can I get this responsive navigation to slide up/ down correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create something similar to bootstraps responsive navigation. When I reduce the screen size so that the media-queries kick in, I click on the menu button and the ul slides down. But when I click on the menu button again, the ul sides up but then immediately slides back down. How can I prevent this from happening? Also, bonus points, when I click the menu button and the ul slides down, the background to the right of the menu button is a different color from the rest of the ul/nav. Is there any way to keep the background consistant across the entire nav?

Here's the jsFiddle with panes: http://jsfiddle.net/scottm28/mRbPd/

Full Screen : http://jsfiddle.net/scottm28/mRbPd/embedded/result/

Comment: `if / else` statements don't work like that in javascript. Use brackets, especially for cohesive reading purposes. This will fix your problem.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Sure enough, this is what happens when you try to juggle to many languages. That fixed problem A, but I'm still having problems with the background-color inconsistencies.

Comment: This looks like you're using a gradient. Then you change the height of an element the gradient's dithering stretches to fit the element. What did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding brackets ...

http://jsfiddle.net/mRbPd/2/

I believe the different background colours is due to a CSS rendering bug, as it sometimes renders it correctly and sometimes doesn't. You could always apply the gradients in a class, and quickly remove then reapply them if you're that desperate for it to work.

This *sort of* fixes the gradient issue, http://jsfiddle.net/mRbPd/3/ but I imagine it's quite inefficient reapplying the class as it would mean the browser has to redraw the gradient.

Comment: That fixed it. Any idea as to what is causing the background-color to the right of the button to change when the button is pressed?

Comment: I just noticed that the problem only accours in chrome and not Safari. I haven't tested it in FF or IE yet.

Comment: Firefox is fine, IE9 too, and even Opera. Dam Chrome ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I added `{}` to the else statement and it works fine for me now: http://jsfiddle.net/mRbPd/1/